# Question on the Definition of L-Group

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

I have a somewhat stupid question whose answer will most likely be "Obviously, yes."  I just want to make sure I am getting the technical details down before I move forward.

Let $\psi_0 = (X, \Phi, X^{\vee},\Phi^{\vee})$ be a root datum, where $X= X(T)$.  To any automorphism $f$ of $X$, let $^t f$ denote the *dual isomorphism* of $X^{\vee}$.  Then $f \mapsto \, ^t f$ is a *bijective antihomomorphism*.

An *automorphism of root data* is an isomorphism $X \rightarrow X$ which permutes $\Phi$, and whose dual map $X^{\vee} \rightarrow X^{\vee}$ permutes $\Phi^{\vee}$.

Let $\psi_0^{\vee} = (X^{\vee}, \Delta^{\vee}, X, \Delta)$ be the dual root datum.  Then $f \mapsto \, ^t f$ gives a bijective antihomomorphism $\textrm{Aut}(\psi_0) \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(\psi_0^{\vee})$.

One has an interest in making an isomorphism between these last two groups, rather than a bijective antihomomorphism.  For example, in the definition of L-group (Borel, *Automorphic L-functions* in Corvallis II), $\psi_0$ is the based root datum of a connected, reductive $k$-group $G$, and $\psi_0^{\vee}$ is the root datum of a $\overline{k}$-group $G^{\vee}$, and one composes various maps to obtain a homomorphism

$$\textrm{Gal}(k_s/k) \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(\psi_0) \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(\psi_0^{\vee}) \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(G^{\vee})$$

and the $L$-group $^L G$ is defined as the semidirect product of $G^{\vee}$ with $\textrm{Gal}(k_s/k)$.  In order for this composition to be a homomorphism, the middle map should be defined by the formula

$$f \mapsto \, ^t f^{-1}$$

rather than $f \mapsto \, ^t f$.  Is this correct?